# IE Uses Courier Font when "font-family: monospace" is used

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have some (test) HTML like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Test Monospace</title>
  <style>
  tt { font-family: monospace; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Test Monospace</h1>
  <p>This is normal text</p>
  <p><tt>This is monospaced text</tt></p>
</body>

</html>
```

When I display this in IE the monospace text uses Courier New instead of the font I have configured in IE.  If I do nothing other than delete the `<style>...</style>` block, it correctly uses the configured font.

It only does this for IE, not FF or GC. IE 9 on Windows 7.

It does this regardless of where the style's configured, including a separate stylesheet or using a style attribute.

The real problem is that specifying the font-family and font-size is key to fixing the browser's problems with monospace text using the following styles:

```
/* monospaced sizes are horribly broken in browser default stylesheets */
code, kbd, pre, samp, tt {
    font-family     : monospace,monospace; /* Chrome   (but note that this makes IE use "Courier New" for some strange reason, as does plain monospace.) */
    font-size       : 1em;                 /* Firefox, IE,Opera */
    }
```

Does anyone know how to stop IE from doing this?

Comment: conditional ie comment tags and a different style for ie

Answer (score 4):

`monospace` is not a specific font familiy. Exactly like `serif` or `sans-serif`, which are generic family definitions.

`font-family: monospace;` just tells the browser to use the default "[monospaced font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font)", which in this case is Courier New. See also [this resource](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-family.asp).

**EDIT:**

If you omit the `font-family` rule for `tt` in your CSS, IE9 seems to display the custom set plain text font. Please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sVCwd/1/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Should it not use the browser's configured "Plain text font"?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "plain text font"… how would a non plain text font look like? Anyway, the sole criterion of a monospace font is that all glyphs have the same fixed width. Please see chapter 15.3.1.5 here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#generic-font-families

Comment: IE allows you to configure two fonts in Internet Options, the "Web Page" font and the "Plain Text" font. The latter allows selection of only monospaced fonts. As a user I expected that whenever text was displayed in monospace it would use the font as configured. It is surprising and annoying to me as a web author that I cannot tell IE to use the monospace font ***which the user has chosen***.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. I'll try if I can reproduce this behaviour in IE9 / Win7

Comment: That's true... my question says as much.  It then goes on to say why I am specifying a font-family.

Comment: The text in these fonts selection window reads "The fonts you select here are displayed on webpages and documents *that do not have a specified text font*". I guess that the pages where font *is specified* with CSS (even as generic font family like `monospace`) don't math this definition.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that in IE, `monospace` means Courier New. Changing the IE settings for “plain text font” affects the default font for some elements, like `tt`, but it does not change the meaning of `monospace`. In an [old discussion](http://www.itlisting.org/2-internet-explorer/0e22ad2e8649d45c.aspx) someone who seems to know what he says writes: “(Please, no comments about the serif and monospace fonts which can be
selected using Tools, Internet Options.  They have nothing to do with the
default CSS generic fonts.)”

If you want, as an IE user, to change the meaning of `monospace`, I suppose you would need to find an entry in Windows registry for it (I was unable to find it in Windows 7 – could not find `IEFixedFontName` for example).

But if you instead just want some elements rendered in a monospace font of your preference (which is mostly the same thing as far as practical effects are considered), you could set up a user style sheet with content like

```
code, kbd, pre, samp, tt, xmp, listing, plaintext {
    font-family: Consolas !important;
}
```

Comment: Well, I rather want some elements rendered in the monospace font  of my *users* preference.

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey, the problem is that your users cannot express their preference by just setting “plain text font”, because IE does not work that way. They can modify the registry or, more realistically, set up a user style sheet. If they use a style sheet without `!important`, then you, as an author, would override their setting if you set `font-family: monospace`.

Comment: What stylesheet rule could the user create which specified a particular font to be used for any element with font-family=monospace?  (And, just BTW, author styles by default override non-important user styles.)

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey, none. In CSS, they can only assign properties to elements, not change the meanings of keywords like `monospace`. And my point was indeed that e.g. author’s `tt { font-family: monospace; }` would override user’s `tt { font-family: Consolas }` (in the absence of `!important`).

Comment: (Sorry about the second point - I misread you to say I needed to use `!important`.)

Comment: IE allows you to configure two fonts in Internet Options, the "Web Page" font and the "Plain Text" font. The latter allows selection of only monospaced fonts. As a user I expected that whenever text was displayed in monospace it would use the font as configured. It is surprising and annoying to me as a web author that I cannot tell IE to use the monospace font ***which the user has chosen***.

Comment: It is surprising and annoying indeed. The best way to tell IE to use, for some inline text, the monospace font chosen by the user (via the settings, or by not doing anything) is to use the `<tt>` markup, or some other markup that causes monospace font by default, **and not set `font-family` at all** on that element.

Comment: That works for IE, but then good ol' Google Chrome makes the font very small.  Explicitly setting font family to `monospace,monospace` suppresses the Google font resizing (and does the same for older FF, although current FF does not make the default monospace font small anymore).

Comment: +1 for Consolas. I use monospace a lot and hate courier.