# Font family in pseudo element

Tags: css, internet-explorer, pseudo-element, css-tables

It seems Internet Explorer 8,9,10 uses here always the same (system) font. In fact Internet Explorer doesn't care about the `font-family` at all. The important thing is the combination of `display:table-cell` and `:before` or `:after`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>

        body > div {
            display: table;
        }

        body > div > div:before {
            font-family: monospace;
            display: table-cell;
            content: 'Not a monospace font in IE.';
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this a known bug? Can't find anything about it.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14698234/ie-uses-courier-font-when-font-family-monospace-is-used?rq=1

Comment: Nope, that's not the problem! When I switch to `display: inline-block;` it works. has nothing to do with `monospace`. If you want put any other real font in it.

Comment: is your pseudo element working in IE7?

Comment: Is this whole demo necessary to reproduce the issue or can it be simplified?

Comment: @user1671639 Sorry I'll fix this.

Comment: @WesleyMurch The important thing is `display: table-cell;` combined with `:before` or `:after`.

Comment: Using this in ie9 and it's fine. http://jsfiddle.net/pymu7wvq/ It is using Courier New.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/KnfaW/

It seems to me that `display: table-cell` causes the problem.

> User agents must ignore the following properties with :before and :after pseudo-elements: 'position', 'float', list properties, and table properties.
>
> The :before and :after pseudo-elements elements allow values of the 'display' property as follows:
>
> If the subject of the selector is a block-level element, allowed values are 'none', 'inline', 'block', and 'marker'. If the value of the 'display' has any other value, the pseudo-element will behave as if the value were 'block'.
> If the subject of the selector is an inline-level element, allowed values are 'none' and 'inline'. If the value of the 'display' has any other value, the pseudo-element will behave as if the value were 'inline'.

[W3C CSS2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html)

So instead of `display: table-cell` use `display: block`. It will work as expected. IE's error handling may be buggy in this case as my opinion.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. But can't find anything about it.

Comment: The suggestion `display: block` is unfortunately not a solution in my case; which also was not the question. And I would say Internet Explorer's exception handling here IS as bug, because it doesn't behave like a `block` as it ignores the property `font-family`, which is not a `position`, `float`, list or table property. Also  all browsers, even the Internet Explorer, ignores the specification, because they treat the pseudo element as `table-cell`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vE35V/
Look into this. I hope it helps you finding a workaround to your problem.